# X11 without backing store

Tags: x11, xlib

I need to test an X11 application for its behavior when the X server does not use a backing store for the application's windows (see https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/backing-store.html). I.e., I want the server to ask the application to redraw "damaged" parts of the window by generating `Expose` events.

The problem is that on my current platform, Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon, the X server seems to always use backing store, and also when I don't ask for it.

I have also tried to install some old versions of Ubuntu (back to Ubuntu 14.04), but they also seem to always use backing store.

Question: Is there a way to disable use of backing store on Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon? If not, is there another recent Linux distribution where this is possible? If not, does anyone have any idea what I need to do to be able to test without backing store?

EDIT: Turns out that Ubuntu 10.04 has backing store disabled by default, i.e., the behavior that I am after, and Ubuntu 12.04 does not. However, it is a hassle to depend on Ubuntu 10.04 because it is no longer supported by Canonical. It would be great if anybody has input on how that behavior can be achieved on a contemporary distribution.

Answer (score 0):

'*backing-store*' is a window attribute, which can be set either at [window creation](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XCreateWindow.html) or via [XChangeWindowAttributes](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XChangeWindowAttributes.html).

e.g.

```
long attr_mask = CWBackingStore | CWEventMask;

XSetWindowAttributes attr = { 
    .backing_store = NotUseful,
    .event_mask    = ExposureMask //among others 
};

XUnmapWindow(dpy, win); //maybe not necessary
XChangeWindowAttributes(dpy, win, attr_mask, &attr);
XMapWindow(dpy, win); //maybe not necessary
```

**Note** (see https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/backing-store.html):

> A backing-store attribute of NotUseful advises the X server that maintaining contents is unnecessary, although some X implementations may still choose to maintain contents and, therefore, not generate Expose events.

---

**Another possibility:**

Start the xserver with the command line parameter (see [man xserver](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xserver))

- **bs** disables backing store support on all screens.

---

**Based on the comment below:**

I don't understand why it should not be relevant to (be able to) '**disable**' the backing-store via client? The value `NotUseful` disables backing-store for the specific window (if supported by the server, see Note above).

Otherwise, there are only two options left, either via command line argument (see above) or via `xorg.conf`.

e.g.

add in the directory (`/etc/X11/`)`xorg.conf.d` a file named `10-backing-store.conf` with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
  Option "BackingStore" "off"
EndSection
```

Restart X (or the machine) and see what happens (locate the log file `Xorg.0.log` - either in `/var/log` or `~/.local/share/xorg` - and look for the token "Backing store", e.g. `less Xorg.0.log | grep "Backing store"`).

Of course, both options requires super user privileges and a restart.

Comment: The client side of this is not relevant, because I am already not asking for backing store. I did notice that the X-server has that option. I don't know whether it will have the desired effect, now how I can change that option without starting X myself.

Comment: Very interesting with you suggestion on adding `10-backing-store.conf`. I'll let you know if that works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Also, `NotUseful` is already what the client sends to the server. It is the default, and I also verified it with `xwininfo`. Regardless, the server chooses to use a backing store anyway, which it is allowed to do according to X protocol spec.